# Why does the image on the bottom left corner I obtained by the following code has more height than others?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create an image grid with HTML and CSS and following is the code I used. As I you can see in the picture I have attached to this. The picture on the bottom left corner has a bigger height than other images. Can someone kindly tell me why this happens and how can I make the image as same as the other images? Thank you.

[image: Image Grid]

Code - HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Float Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Float Test</h1>

    <ul class="float-test">
        <li>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521651201144-634f700b36ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80">
            </figure>
        </li><li>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500479694472-551d1fb6258d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80">
            </figure>
        </li><li>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1456926631375-92c8ce872def?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80">
            </figure>
        </li><li>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489084917528-a57e68a79a1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80">
            </figure>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="float-test">
        <li>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484557985045-edf25e08da73?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80">
            </figure>
        </li>
    <li>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504618223053-559bdef9dd5a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80">
            </figure>
        </li>
    <li>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477764250597-dffe9f601ae8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80">
            </figure>
        </li>
    <li>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453227588063-bb302b62f50b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80">
            </figure>
        </li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Code: CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.float-test {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.float-test li {
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.flaot-test li figure {
    width: 100%;
}

.float-test li figure img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: check the link you will see 1576 where all the other are at 750 or 1500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the image is a different size then the others (it's slightly larger). You can fix this either by limiting that specific images height or by using a program like photoshop to change the size of the image.

Comment: I'm asking this, because I am a beginner. But the other images I chose are of different sizes. Why didn't this behavior apply to other images? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's because the other images have the same aspect ratio except for that one (it appears to be higher than the rest)